# Set seekbar progress programmatically Android

Tags: android, listener, seekbar

I have two seekbar. I want to see progress in seekbar one when I move thumb 2. please help 
is this possible?

```
  android:id="@+id/seekbarone"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

  android:max="100"

  android:maxHeight="8dp"
  ...
```

```
  android:id="@+id/seekbartwo"

  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

  android:max="100"

  android:maxHeight="8dp"
  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeekBar sb1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbarone);
SeekBar sb2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbartwo);
sb2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                sb1.setProgress(progress);

            }
        });
```